# Authorize and Unauthorize by adding and remove user to a group

Tags: users, group, reboot, access-control, authorization

I want to authorize (or unauthorise) by adding (or removing) user to a group. Is it possible to have the changes be effective immediately without having to reboot?

I just want to give one time access to a folder to a user and revoke it later.

## Edit

Also is it possible without logout?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, adding users to groups and removing them from groups will not require a reboot, but it will require that user to log out and then log back in (if they are logged in when the change is made). Without knowing more about your specific situation, I can't say if there are any caveats to that, but I would be surprised if an actual reboot wasrequired.

Comment: Edit: Also is it possible without logout? I just want to give one time access to a folder to a user and revoke it later.

Comment: Membership in a group will take effect (or revocation of that membership) for a user only at login/logout. You can, however, change the group ownership of the directory in question, or use ACLs to grant immediate access (or revoke access immediately).

Comment: So we have to change group ownership recursively right? Can you elaborate a bit on ACL? What are its pros and cons?